# How to change profile picture using TWRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter, twrequest

How to change profile picture using TWRequest  ,
I post to timeLine using this code

-(IBAction)postToTwitter
{
    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

```
// Request access from the user to access their Twitter account
[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) 
 {
     // Did user allow us access?
     if (granted == YES)
     {
         // Populate array with all available Twitter accounts
         NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

         // Sanity check
         if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) 
         {
             // Keep it simple, use the first account available
             ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];

             // Build a twitter request

            //http://api.twitter.com/1/account/update_profile_image.json  
             //https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json

             TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json"] parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

             //NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.selectedImage);
            NSData *myData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.selectedImage, 0.5);

             [postRequest addMultiPartData:myData withName:@"media" type:@"image/jpg"];

             [postRequest setAccount:acct];

             // Block handler to manage the response
             /*      
              [postRequest addMultiPartData:[base64 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] // base64 is an NSString of the encoded image

              withName:@"image"

              type:@"multipart/form-data"];

              // Post the request*/

             [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) 
              {
                  NSLog(@"Twitter response, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
              }
              ];


     }
    }
 }];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this too, using Apple's WWDC11 slides as a guide, but it seems Twitter has changed the API since then (or the slide had a bug).

The solution is simple: you need to use a multipart data name of "image" instead of "media".  And I think the type should be "image/jpeg", not "image/jpg".

So change that line as follows:

```
[postRequest addMultiPartData:myData withName:@"image" type:@"image/jpeg"];
```